# Filter a user's answers based on tags

Tags: support, tags, answers, search

On the user profile page, one can sort the answers based on votes, newest, views and recent. Although this is really helpful, it would be even better if users can filter out the answers based on the tags.

I am sure for those who have answered too many questions, it would be a pain without this feature if they need to refer to their previous answers for any reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever gone into your own profile, or anyone else's for that matter, and clicked on the tags at the bottom?

Do that, see what you return.

Comment: Hint: it puts "[tagname] userid:12345" in as a search

Comment: Oh yes ... its been quite a while I've been using SO and never noticed!!! If you want to search on multiple tags then in the search you can specify user:39289 [xml][xslt]. This lists all your answers where the questions have both the tags. This has made my search for my own answers a lot easier. Thanks both of you :D